# How to add a pager template suggestion for current page number?

Tags: theming

I'm trying to add a Twig template suggestion for list pages via pagers, so that I can theme the first page differently than the next pages.

I have been able to successfully add a template suggestion with the following code.

```
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  $path = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
  $strip_path = parse_url($path, PHP_URL_QUERY);

  $new_path = str_replace("page=", "pager", $strip_path);
  $new_path = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $new_path);

  if (!empty($new_path)) {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__' . $new_path;
  }
}
```

At the moment I'm getting *page--pager.html.twig* as a suggestion on the pager pages only, not the first page of the list, (*it is desired*).

If Drupal URL is **/something?page=[some-number]** the above suggestion is provided, however, if it is just **/something** template suggestion is not suggested.

In Devel profiler, I have not seen any extra overhead or memory usage.

Is it the right way, or is there any better way?

Comment: Thing is that this snippet now fires on every single page, doesn't it? Not just on pagers, and not just on the first pager page. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, at the moment, it is being fired on every single page, not just the pagers pages.

Comment: I updated the title to clarify :)

Comment: Thank you, however, I do not get a template suggestion on any other page, other than a page with query string ?page > 0. Hope that clarifies it further.

Comment: Absolutely! Maybe you can update your question to add both comments directly into your question. Which will help others to quickly get what's really important.